# Generate DeviceId and DevicePassword for crmsvctutil

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to generate code using crmsvcutil. I have CRM Online. I have used DeviceRegistration project present in SDK for device id and device password generation. But the generated device id is of length 26, while using this device id in crmsvcutil, it throws error that the device id length should be between 12 and 22 characters.

Comment: your crm online use live id or office 365 authentication?

Comment: I am using using live id.

Comment: are you using the latest sdk? currently is 5.0.16 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004

Comment: Yes I am using 5.0.16. Below is the crmsvctuil command format I am using. <<<crmsvcutil /connectionString:"Authentication Type=Passport; Server=https://XXXX.crm5.dynamics.com/XXXX; User ID=microsoft-live-id; Password=password; Device ID=XXXXX; Device Password=XXXXX" /namespace:Orgn.Xrm /dataContextPrefix:Orgn /out:Xrm.cs>>>

Comment: I am using DeviceRegistration /operation:Register

Comment: inside your deviceid and password there are quotation marks (") or equal characters (=)?

Comment: There is no quotation mark or equal to characters(" or =).

Comment: try with this `CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:http://XXXX.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /out:Xrm.cs /username:email@email.com /password:password /deviceid:XXX /devicepassword:YYY /namespace:Orgn.Xrm /serviceContextName:Orgn`

Comment: Getting error "One of either the /server or /connectionString is required."

Comment: just tested, i wrote https instead of http and quotation marks are necessary for the usernames and passwords, so the right one is:
`CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:https://XXXX.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /out:Xrm.cs /username:"email@email.com" /password:"password" /deviceid:"XXX" /devicepassword:"YYY" /namespace:Orgn.Xrm /serviceContextName:Org`